# What is the maximum length of a command line in Mac OS X?

Tags: mac-osx, bash

I'm generating models in Ruby on Rails, and some of these tables have an awful lot of columns. What's maximum length of a command in Mac OS X?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The limit is not in bash but in your operating system. It's defined by the value of `ARG_MAX` in your OS's `limits.h`. You can get the value by running `getconf ARG_MAX`. On my OSX 10.5 machine (and most other BSD systems) it's 262144. You can read more about this limit [here](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/).

Comment: On Solaris 10, it is 1048320 - both are so big that they boggle the mind that someone might run out of it.

Comment: Excellent.  I guess I was a was away yet. lol

Comment: As of macOS 10.12, the limit is still 262,144 (256 KB). Note that the limit only applies when invoking _external utilities_, not shell builtins. Compare `echo "$(printf "%$(getconf ARG_MAX)s")"` to `/bin/echo "$(printf "%$(getconf ARG_MAX)s")"`

Comment: High Sierra (10.13.1) here, still `262144`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Searching through a few thousand files will quickly make that number *very* small.

Comment: Catalina 10.15 and still 262144 and I regularly run in to this when moving or copying large numbers of files with mv/cp/rm. It'll do about 5000ish before it complains.

Comment: Big Sur 11.2.1 `getconf ARG_MAX` prints 1048576.  In your face, Solaris!!!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the shell, but the last time I ran a configure script using zsh on 10.6 it was 65535 characters.